# Running Hyper-V Manager behind NAT

Tags: nat, hyper-v

I am running Hyper-V Manager on a Windows 8.1 box behind a router (actually a VMware Fusion VM). When I try to connect to my Hyper-V box, I get an error

```
RPC server unavailable. Unable to establish communication between 'SERVER' and 'CLIENT'
```

where SERVER is my Hyper-V box and CLIENT is my Windows 8.1 box.

I configured NAT to forward ports 135, 137, 138 and 139. Does Hyper-V Manager use even more ports?

Comment: Having a NAT between a Windows client and a server is bad juju.  Is there some reason why you can't use bridged networking?

Comment: I don't want my VMs to be loose on the network. Also, I want to know how to administer Hyper-V hosts outside a private network.

Comment: If you want to administer machines on a private network, then you create a VPN to that private network.  You generally don't try to do it through a NAT.

Comment: not helpful... if he needs to NAT into the hyperv server and manage it from remote, it's probably because VPN is not an option